# some problem when client receive messages from server though socket

Tags: java, sockets, encoding

in my server code:

```
pw = new PrintWriter(stream);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

in my client code

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
OutputStreamWriter stream = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(stream);
```

then
    at first, server use:
    pw.println("OK");
    pw.flush();

client receive OK

After that, server use:

```
pw.println("TRUE")
pw.flush();
```

this time, client receive a string that has unknow char

```
\ufffd\ufffdTRUE
```

then i keep send msg to client and it will receive some \ufffd before every sentence.

Could anybody help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that the server resends byte order markers (0xFFFE 0xFFFF), which are replaced by the replacement character (0xFFFD) at the client side.
Do you re-create the print writer before each send on the server side?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Each time, i used the same print writer, i don't what happened.

Comment: But if the server and client is on the same machine, it works normally. but now my server is on a machine installed win server2003 and the client is on windows 7, then the problem occur.

Comment: i see that each time i call method readline to read data from server,it will read one \ufffd after \r\n. so the first time it will give me "OK" directly, the sencond time it will give me a \ufffd before "TRUE" and 2 \ufffd at the third time and so on. Do you have any ideas? Translate data through different jres will cause this problem? So sorry to disturb you.

Comment: Finally i found the reason. I used the function setUrgentData(0XFF) of Socket to let server know that client is alive. When server and client are on the same machine, client will ignore the 0XFF. But if they are on different PCs, client will recognize the OXFF as received data. I don't know why.