# Qt Client received junk characters in addition to expected string

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I am implementing a simple Qt based client which sends one command at a time to **NON_QT** server and server responds back. Once I get a reply from server I use it to for other purposes depending on the response

Everything works as expected. Only slight glitch is I am receiving strings like

```
command_accepted\u0000\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD
```

While specs of the server say expected response is **"command_accepted"**.
So Ii am bit clueless as to why I am getting those weird letters. Please advise me.

```
void ClientForNonQtServer::getResponse()
{

  QTextStream stream( sockForClient );
  QString line;
 forever
    {

   if( nextBlockSize == 0 )
     {
       if( sockForClient ->bytesAvailable() < sizeof( quint16  ) )
         {
           break;
         }
       stream >> nextBlockSize;
     }
   if( sockForClient ->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize )
     {
       break;
     }
     stream >> line;
     if( !line.isNull() )
       {
         qDebug()<< " stream is "<< line;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: The client and the server side may be using different encodings.

Comment: Can you please give me idea how would I make client to use same encoding.  Client is running on UBuntu an d Server on windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357556/some-problem-when-client-receive-messages-from-server-though-socket

Answer (score 0):

From Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-gt-gt-4)

> **QTextStream & QTextStream::operator>>(QString & str)**
>
> Reads a word from the stream and stores it in str, then returns a
> reference to the stream. Words are separated by whitespace (i.e., all
> characters for which QChar::isSpace() returns true).

So, everything works as expected. I believe, it would be better to use [QTextStream::readLine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#readLine) or [QTextStream::read](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#read) here.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is on the server side.